# How to present 2 types of json on the same view each one at a time based on button click

Tags: angularjs, json, html, angular

I have a view with 2 buttons: `List 1` & `List 2`

in my html I have an action when someone click on `List 1` im bringing the json for `List 1` and presenting it, and I have an action that when I click on `List 2` I get the json for `list 2`,

but I dont know how to present it cause its in a different struct then the list that comes back for `List 1`...
 what would be the better solution to print 2 different structure of json but on the same view? so if `List 2` was click I want to delete `List 1` from the view and show `List 2` and vice versa.

this is my component.ts:

```
export class MyCmp implements OnInit {

  list1Data: Observable<List1Bulk[]>;
  list2Data: Observable<List2Bulk[]>

  constructor(private _myService: MyService) {
  };

  public showList1(): void {
    this.list1Data = this._myService.getList1Data();
  }

  public showList2(): void {
    this.list2Data = this._myService.getList2Data();
  }
}
```

and this is my component.html:

```
<div>
  <!-- list 1 button -->
  <button md-button
          (click)="showList1Data()"
          class="md-primary">List1</button>

  <!-- list 2 button -->
  <button md-button
          (click)="showList2Data()"
          class="md-primary">List2</button>

<md-content>
<h1 align="center">{{title}}</h1>
<h2>lists:</h2>
  <div class="list-bg"  *ngFor="#bulk of list1Data | async">
    ID: {{bulk.id}} Number of Items: {{bulk.numberOfItems}}
  </div>
</md-content>
```

How can I change my view so I can present also list2data? i want to click on  List 2 button , clear List 1 data and present List 2 data..

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*ngIf` or `*ngSwitch` for this. In your `MyCmp` declare 2 boolean properties `showingList1` and `showingList2`. Update these properties accordingly when buttons are clicked. Then your template will be something like this:

```
<div>
<!-- list 1 button -->
<button md-button
        (click)="showList1Data()"
        class="md-primary">List1</button>

<!-- list 2 button -->
<button md-button
        (click)="showList2Data()"
        class="md-primary">List2</button>

<md-content>
<h1 align="center">{{title}}</h1>
<h2>lists:</h2>
<div *ngIf="showingList1">
    <div class="list-bg"  *ngFor="#bulk of list1Data | async">
        ID: {{bulk.id}} Number of Items: {{bulk.numberOfItems}}
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="showingList2">
    <div class="list-bg"  *ngFor="#bulk of list2Data | async">
        ID: {{bulk.id}} Number of Items: {{bulk.numberOfItems}}
    </div>
</div>
</md-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply combine the two properties like this:

```
export class MyCmp implements OnInit {

      listData: Observable<List1Bulk[] | List2Bulk[]>;

      constructor(private _myService: MyService) {};

      public showList1(): void {
        this.listData = this._myService.getList1Data();
      }

      public showList2(): void {
        this.listData = this._myService.getList2Data();
      }
}
```

This way you don't need to change anything in your HTML.